# Network Configuration for IP Camera Setup

Tags: router, home-networking, ip-camera

I am currently sharing my internet connection with my neighbor and have the following network setup:

```
MyDSLModem (Internet)
|
MyRouter (192.168.1.1) ─┬─ (192.168.1.2) MyPC1
                        ├─ (192.168.1.X) NeighborRouter (192.168.2.1) ─┬─ (192.168.2.X) NeighborPC1
                        ├─ (192.168.1.X) MyPC2                         ├─ (192.168.2.X) NeighborPC2
                        ├─ (192.168.1.X) MyPC3                         ├─ (192.168.2.X) NeighborPC3
                        :                                              :
                        :                                              :
                        └─ etc.                                        └─ etc.
```

We are planning to buy a 8ch surveillance camera system, of which the DVR unit will be installed under my neighbor's LAN network (192.168.2.X). The resulting configuration would then be as follows:

```
MyDSLModem (Internet)
|
MyRouter (192.168.1.1) ─┬─ (192.168.1.2) MyPC1
                        ├─ (192.168.1.X) NeighborRouter (192.168.2.1) ─┬─ (192.168.2.X) NeighborPC1
                        ├─ (192.168.1.X) MyPC2                         ├─ (192.168.2.X) NeighborPC2
                        ├─ (192.168.1.X) MyPC3                         ├─ (192.168.2.X) NeighborPC3
                        :                                              ├─ (192.168.2.X) NeighborDVR_Unit
                        :                                              :
                        └─ etc.                                        └─ etc.
```

My question is, would I be able to access the DVR unit's webserver on 192.168.2.X from a PC on my network (192.168.1.X)? If not, what changes do I need to make, as much as possible without resorting to changing my network IP configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your current setup, I would guess that the default gateway for your PCs is 192.168.1.1, which means you would not be able to access the DVR.

Your best options are to either add a static route to 192.168.1.1, or connect the DVR to your network. Both options would allow both you and your neighbor to connect to the DVR.